# How to put just a label in a Joomla xml file

Tags: xml, joomla, label

I'm writing an xml file as part of a Joomla component. It looks like this

```
<field name="height" type="text" default="" label="Height:" description="DESCRIPTION_HEIGHT" />
```

That gives me a text box with the label, which is great but what I am trying to do is just have a label, it's going to seperate the options and give a bit of detail about the options below it. I've tried a few things but they either don't show up or show up as a text box. I'd really appreciate any insight you could give me, thanks.

Update:

I found the answer, hopefully it will benefit someone else at some point.

```
<field name="spacer" type="spacer" default="" label="label title here" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also add styling to the spacers which comes in very handy when you want to make them stand out.

```
<param name="@spacer" type="spacer" default="&lt;div id=&quot;image_1&quot;  style=&quot;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;color:#fff;padding:4px;margin:0;background:#666;&quot;&gt;Spacer 1 Styling&lt;/div&gt;" label="" description="" />
```

Dont forget that if you want each spacer to be styled differently, that you give each one a different name like spacer1, spacer2 and so on ;)

Hope this helps